# Why does root user cannot create browser sandbox?

Tags: chrome, browser, sandbox

> Error: Running as root without `--no-sandbox` is not supported.

- In Linux, why cannot the root user create sandbox for chrome or opera browsers like other users?
- Why should the root user need to launch the browser with `--no-sandbox` args?
- What is the significance in security of browser while using without sandbox?
- Are there any ways to create sandbox environment in browser for root users?

Answer (score 5):

> In linux, why cannot the root user create sandbox for chrome or opera browsers like other users?

There are several known ways to break out of sandboxes if you can have full root privileges within the sandbox; the makers of Chrome and Opera apparently don't want to claim that their particular sandboxing technologies are proof against attacks of that type.

> Why should the root user need to launch the browser with --no-sandbox args?

So that the user will be aware that the sandboxing feature is not to be relied upon if running as root.

> Why should the root user need to launch the browser with --no-sandbox args?
>
> Are there any ways to create sandbox environment in browser for root users?

The general recommendation is to not run a web browser as root, period.

A web browser is a large and very complicated program that routinely needs to deal with incoming untrusted data from the network that may or may not be actually crafted with hostile intent. You would generally want to run such programs with the absolute minimum possible privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a browser as root by `un-sandboxing` it.

I made a simple script that can help enable or disable different browsers in root. The script will present you a menu which will enable or disable a browser based on your selection.

[**Github repo link**](https://github.com/david-kariuki/linux-unsandbox-browsers-cli)

[Profile link](https://github.com/david-kariuki/)

Use the profile link incase the repo link wount work.